# Need help understanding this lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

```
return View(db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem in understanding this?

Comment: The statement returns a View (so it's most like an ASP.NET MVC web app) and gets the first student from the `Students` database entity collection that matches the `StudentID` with the value `id` (or returns `NULL` if none is found - that's what the `FirstOrDefault` stands for - return first match - or NULL is nothing matches). That `Student` object is passed to the view as the model for the view to be displayed

Comment: The lambda, thank you now is clear to me.

Comment: Nitpick: the lambda is only this part: `x => x.StudentID == id`

Comment: Yeah I understand that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lambda expression is sorting through a collection (`Students`) and returning either the **first** instance that it finds where `StudentID` has the same value as `id` or `null` if it can't find one.